# PHP - Exec File Path Errors (Tesseract)

Tags: php, exec, tesseract

I have ran tesseract in the commandline and got results back ok but now i am using the same command with PHP exec it will not work.

The command is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe" "C:\xampp\htdocs\Atoms Projects\Tesseract\text.jpeg" "C:\xampp\htdocs\Atoms Projects\Tesseract\Out.txt"
```

I tried this code:

```
exec("C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe" "C:\xampp\htdocs\Atoms Projects\Tesseract\text.jpeg" "C:\xampp\htdocs\Atoms Projects\Tesseract\Out.txt");
print_r($msg);
```

How can i make the command work correctly?

Also is there any way to send in multiple lines? to split into vars like:

```
$exe = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe";
$img = "C:\xampp\htdocs\User Projects\Tesseract\text.jpeg";
$txt = "C:\xampp\htdocs\User Projects\Tesseract\Out.txt";
```

This is also not working:

```
$exe = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe";
$img = "C:\xampp\htdocs\Atoms Projects\Tesseract\text.jpeg";
$txt = "C:\xampp\htdocs\Atoms Projects\Tesseract\Out";
$output = exec("\"$exe\" \"$img\" \"$txt\" "); 
print_r($output);
```

I am using XAMPP on Windows OS.

Comment: i think you want like this  ` $output = exec( $exe $img $txt);
print_r($output ); `

Comment: Gives the error - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$img' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: `$exe = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe";
$img = "C:\xampp\htdocs\User Projects\Tesseract\text.jpeg";
$txt = "C:\xampp\htdocs\User Projects\Tesseract\Out.txt"; $output = exec( $exe $img $txt); print_r($output ); `

Comment: Same error again, i am running this on XAMPP, Win7 OS by the way so perhaps that causes errors since most are using linux.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution which was to change all \ characters to / in the 3 paths like this:

```
$exe = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe";
$img = "C:/xampp/htdocs/Atoms Projects/Tesseract/text.jpeg";
$txt = "C:/xampp/htdocs/Atoms Projects/Tesseract/Out";
$output = exec("\"$exe\" \"$img\" \"$txt\" "); 
print_r($output);
```